# Instant power off programmatically?

Tags: acpi

Under Windows XP Pro in a networked environment such that Ctrl+Alt+Del gives you the Windows Security prompt, if you hold Ctrl and click shutdown it triggers an Emergency Shutdown.

This appears to turn off the system so fast it doesn't even what for processes to finish, i.e. almost as if you just pulled the power/long-held the power button.

I am wondering by what process Windows achieves such a quick shutdown - is it instructing the BIOS directly via ACPI/APM to power down the system? If so, how could this be achieved programatically in any language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished on *nix systems by using the system requests feature. Generally this is disabled for security reasons, but you can enable it with root privileges and request power off to the system immediately as follows:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq-trigger ;
echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

where the letter 'o' means "power off". Other functions are available. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Answer (score 1):

The `ExitWindowsEx` function is the standard shutdown, and even with `EWX_FORCE` it still closes all programs, services etc... it just does not *ask* / wait for them to close.

So what's the solution? **Use `NtShutdownSystem`.**

That function does the actual shutdown, by flushing the caches, registry etc and then calling the BIOS to power down the machine.

Look here for an usage example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34194/Performing-emergency-shutdowns

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`ExitWindowsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `EWX_POWEROFF` and `EWX_FORCE` flags set...

Comment: Thanks Yahia, would you know about achieving it in Unix or other OS' in general?

Comment: @deed02392 that depends on the Unix you use and the priviliges your process is running under...

Comment: I'm interested in support for this mainly in FreeBSD and Debian (Xen/OpenVZ). I was hoping to get an explanation in generic terms on how it's achieved so I could do the further reading for specific OS' myself.

Comment: @deed02392 Xen/OpenVZ is a very special case since such actions as shutting down are handled by the virtualization layer and might even be prohibited the "standard way"...

Comment: I don't think it makes a significant difference, except obviously in OpenVZ where trying to do it directly the 'standard way' might actually reference the host. In which case fine, I will not use OpenVZ in my solution, but I would like to know how to programatically power-off a *nix machine by commanding the hardware as directly as possible to remove power.

Comment: I determined the correct method. It worked in VMWare, OpenVZ and Xen without issue.