# Instantly Shut Down/Sleep shortcut

Tags: shutdown

How do I create a shortcut that instantly shuts down the computer in the same way the computer instantly shuts down when holding my power button for 4 seconds. This is for PC.

I tried creating a shortcut using shutdown /s /t 0 but it does not shut down instantly.
thanks.

Comment: Are you going to tell us whether it's  Mac or a PC at all?

Comment: Do you want to write a programm to do that? If so, in which language? Do you have a code example of what you've already tried?

Comment: If a program can do that, yes. Any language is fine.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636059/instant-power-off-programatically

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. That's a hardware feature (cuts power to the machine, doesn't really 'shut down').

Answer (score 0):

While its not quite possible to achieve what you described as it is a hardware feature, I believe you can mimic the behavior by sending **Emergency Shutdown** request to system. The result would be immediate session shutdown which is comparable in time with holding the power button.

In Windows you can achieve this by using `NtShutdownSystem` and `NtSetSystemPowerState`.
There is a very nice article about this topic:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34194/Performing-emergency-shutdowns

in Unix/Posix based system you should be able to do this by using:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq-trigger ;
echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

however you may need to obtain required privileges.